# trying to figure out N / S / E / W side of street w/ Google Maps API

Tags: api, google-maps

Were using Google Maps API to figure out some GIS specific info but we're struggling to get the side of the street that an address or geocode is on. I've looked through stackoverflow and google maps api groups but not seeing too many other people who want/need this.

As an example, `40 St Marks Ave, Brooklyn, NY` is on the S (South) side of the street, we can see this if we plot it using Google Maps, but I'm not seeing where this info is returned when we make an API call.

If it's something that the API really doesn't return, any of you folks have a clever way of figuring that out? Been scratching my head on this one and starting to think that I'm just not looking at it quite the right way.

btw, we definitely need the side of the street info returned as compass coordinates (aka N/S/W/E).

Thanks.

Comment: how knowing N/S/W/E helps figuring out which side of the street you are on?

Answer (score 0):

If I needed to do this I would:

1. look to see if ROOFTOP geocodes are available in the area of interest (they are for ["40 St Marks Ave, Brooklyn, NY"](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=40%20St%20Marks%20Ave,%20Brooklyn,%20NY&geocode=1&type=sat) gives 
   "location_type": "ROOFTOP"), if ROOFTOP geocodes are not available, this probably won't work.
2. get directions from that point to itself (should give you the closest location on the road):
   [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=40%20St%20Marks%20Ave,%20Brooklyn,%20NY&geocode=1&addr2=40%20St%20Marks%20Ave,%20Brooklyn,%20NY&geocode=2)
3. calculate the [bearing](from the street to the building, or vice versa, depending on which gives you what you need).
4. use that to determine the compass direction.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't quite work for us but it was interesting regardless. One of the main issues that we're finding now that we're testing it is  that GPS itself is not accurate enough.

Answer (score -2):

A simple solution that comes to mind is to use a ***timestamp*** on multiple pictures, while moving down the street. From there we can get to know the direction of movement and know whether the building was on the left or right of the street.

Comment: Please add some code and/or trial and errors you performed.